# Twitter ios5 integration

Tags: twitter, ios5, integration

I'm developing an ios5 app and I have integrated twitter. How can I do to share on the tweet a screenshot of the current view in the app? Or how can I display in the initial text a variable  value(I've tried but it makes an error). Thanks!!

Comment: What did you try and what error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

*Never done any of this but it should get you on the right track*

You'll want to capture the current view state to a UIImage and then attach this to the Twitter TWTweetComposeViewController.

For the initial text, you should be able to use `[controller setInitialText:@"Initialtext"];`

Comment: But doing that [controller setInitialText:@"Initialtext"]; how can I put a variable value. Like this [controller setInitialText:@"Variable %i", variable]; (that doesn't work). What is the right form?

Comment: pass `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Variable %d", variable]` instead

Comment: That's perfect!! But now how can I charge the screenshot I take on the tweet? Should I put this: [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]]?